# why my esp-01,while in programming mode (GPIO0 grounded), is disconnecting my other esp-01 from my esp32 access point?

Tags: upload, esp8266

I'm using three parts:

ESP32
mode: STA+AP
send data to: my phone hotspot
IP: 192.168.4.1
server port: 80

ESP-01 (A)
mode: STA+AP
send data to: ESP32
IP: 192.168.0.80
server port: 8080

ESP-01 (B)
mode: STA+AP
send data to: ESP-01 (A) (unsuccessfully yet)
IP: 192.168.0.50
server port: 50

I'm intending to have more esp-01's

the problem is when I make esp(B) in programming mode by connecting GPIO0 to ground and reset it:   the esp(A) stops sending data to esp32 immediately

once I disconnect esp(B), esp(A) sends again normally

I powered the esp(B) by a separate power source and no difference

I played on the channels numbers and still no difference

I know I can just ignore the problem since I will not upload any more but I'm afraid something wrong I did, what to do please?

here is esp32 code:

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>

WiFiServer server(80); 

char Pssid[] = "toOomy";
char Ppass[] = "1222222224";

char assid[] = "my_net";
char apass[] = "1222222224";

int sensor_ID= -1;
float sensor_V= -1;
float sensor_I= -1;
float sensor_P= -1;

void responseToClient(){
    String response= "okok";
    WiFiClient client = server.available();

    if (client) {
        if (client.connected()) {
            Serial.println("connected");
            String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');

            if (sensor_ID == 0){
                response= "1";
            }


            client.flush();
            Serial.println(request);
            client.println(response);              // sends the temperature to the client

            client.stop();                         // disconnects the client
            }

      Serial.println(sensor_ID);
      Serial.println(sensor_V);
      Serial.println(sensor_I);
      Serial.println(sensor_P);

  }
}

void handleNew(){
  //IPAddress newIP(192, 168, 1, 1);
responseToClient();
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

   // starts the WiFi server

   // WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
    WiFi.softAP(assid, apass, 5);
    WiFi.begin(Pssid,Ppass, 5);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.println('.');
        delay(500);
    }
    server.begin();
    Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());
}

void loop() {

    handleNew();

}
```

here is the esp-01's code:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
// #include <ArduinoJson.h>

WiFiClient client;

//// for the first esp-01 ////
IPAddress next_Server_IP1(192, 168, 4, 1); 
int next_server_port1 = 80;

int ID = 1; 
WiFiServer local_server(8080);
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 80);     
char ssid[] = "my_net";       
char pass[] = "1222222224";
char assid[] = "Amy_net1";    
char apass[] = "1222222224";
int wifi_channel= 5;
int softAP_channel= 5;
float V = 230.4;
float I = 2.3;
float P = 2678.9;


//// for the second esp-01 ////
IPAddress next_Server_IP2(192, 168, 0, 80);
int next_server_port2 = 8080;

// int ID = 2; 
// WiFiServer local_server(50);    
// IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 50);  
// char ssid[] = "Amy_net1";       
// char pass[] = "1222222224";
// char assid[] = "Amy_net2";    
// char apass[] = "1222222224";
// int wifi_channel= 5;
// int softAP_channel= 5;
// float V = 200.5;
// float I = 10.5;
// float P = 3000.5;


IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 0, 2); // WiFi router's IP ((I AM NOT SURE WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE))
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);



String answer = "\n";


String SensorData()
{

  String Data = "{\"Sensor_Data\":{"
                "\"sensor_ID\":\"sensor_ID_val\","
                "\"sensor_V\":\"sensor_V_val\","
                "\"sensor_I\":\"sensor_I_val\","
                "\"sensor_P\":\"sensor_P_val\"}}\r";
  Data.replace("sensor_ID_val", String(ID));
  Data.replace("sensor_V_val", String(V));
  Data.replace("sensor_I_val", String(I));
  Data.replace("sensor_P_val", String(P));

  return (Data);
}

void responseToClient()
{
  String response = "Thanks";
  WiFiClient sensorClient = local_server.available();
  if (sensorClient)
  {
    if (sensorClient.connected())
    {
      Serial.println("connected");
      String request = sensorClient.readStringUntil('\r'); // reads the message from the client

      Serial.println(request);

      sensorClient.flush();
      Serial.println(request);
      sensorClient.println(response); // sends the temperature to the client
      sensorClient.stop(); // disconnects the client
    }
  }
}

void requestToServer(String request, IPAddress IP, int port)
{
  if (client.connect(IP, port))
  { // connects to the server
    Serial.println("connected");

    client.println(request);               // trigger message to the server, its value is scrapped
    answer = client.readStringUntil('\r'); // received the server's answer

    Serial.println(String(answer));


    client.stop();


  }
}

  void setup()
  {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);

    WiFi.softAP(assid, apass, softAP_channel);
    // WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
    delay(300);
    WiFi.softAPConfig(ip, gateway, subnet);

    WiFi.begin(ssid, pass, wifi_channel);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(500);
    }
    local_server.begin();
  }


  void loop()
  {
    Serial.println("request:");
    if (ID == 1)
    {
      requestToServer(SensorData(), next_Server_IP1, next_server_port1);
    }
    else if (ID > 1)
    {
Serial.println("ID>1");
      requestToServer(SensorData(), next_Server_IP2, next_server_port2 );
    }

    Serial.println("response:");

    responseToClient();
  }
```

Comment: was it really connected to the esp32 and not to the other esp-01?

Comment: yeah I read the data from the Serial monitor of the esp32.. which sent from the first esp-01.. the other esp-01 supposed to sends a different kind of data